# Is there a way to make every item of a JList have different widths?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, paintcomponent, renderer

I'm trying to display Strings in rows and columns. Since they differ in length and represent parts of a continuous text, I would like each component to only take up the size it needs to show the whole String.

So far, I managed to load the individual items into the list, limit the number of rows and make them wrap horizontally. I now wrote a custom ListCellRenderer as I figured this could solve my problem but it doesn't work the way I had hoped. The two Strings that are part of each item are neither centered nor displayed above one another (in fact, they are not readable at all because they seem to be drawn outside the cell) and they all have the same size. What am I doing wrong?

This is what my Renderer looks like:

```
public class ElementRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<Element> {
    private Element element;

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Element> list, Element value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        element = (Element) value;
        if (element.getTag().equals("N/A"))
            setEnabled(false);
        else
            setEnabled(true);
        if (isSelected)
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredSoftBevelBorder());
        else
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedSoftBevelBorder());
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (!isEnabled())
            setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        String word = element.getWord();
        String tag = element.getTag();

        FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(DataManager.getCurrentFont());
        Rectangle bounds = getVisibleRect();

        int y = bounds.y + ((bounds.height - 2*fm.getHeight())/2) + fm.getAscent();
        g.drawString(word, bounds.x + (bounds.width - fm.stringWidth(word))/2, y);
        g.drawString(tag, bounds.x + (bounds.width - fm.stringWidth(tag))/2, y + fm.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(DataManager.getCurrentFont());
        int wordwidth = fm.stringWidth(element.getWord());
        int tagwidth = fm.stringWidth(element.getTag());
        if (tagwidth > wordwidth)
            wordwidth = tagwidth;
        return new Dimension(17+wordwidth, 3+fm.getHeight()*2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the simplest solution I could find without messing with the `JList`'s `LayoutManager`, nor its `ListUI`, is indeed to create a custom `ListCellRenderer`, but with the following logic:

- The custom `ListCellRenderer` is a `JPanel` with a `DefaultListCellRenderer` in it.
- The custom `ListCellRenderer`, as a `JPanel`, will fill the entire cell space.
- The `DefaultListCellRenderer` will be centered inside our custom `ListCellRenderer`. We can achieve this by setting the `LayoutManager` of the `JPanel` to `GridBagLayout`. Since there will be added only a single component in it (ie the `DefaultListCellRenderer` which is a `JLabel`), it will be centered.

Follows sample code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;

public class Main {
    public static class DynamicWidthListCellRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {
        private final DefaultListCellRenderer delegate;

        public DynamicWidthListCellRenderer() {
            super(new GridBagLayout());
            delegate = new DefaultListCellRenderer();
            super.add(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(final JList list,
                                                      final Object value,
                                                      final int index,
                                                      final boolean isSelected,
                                                      final boolean cellHasFocus) {
            delegate.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            //super.setBackground(delegate.getBackground()); //Test this out also...
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JList<String> list = new JList<>(new String[]{"abc", "abcdefghijklmnop", "abcdefg", "a"});
        list.setCellRenderer(new DynamicWidthListCellRenderer());

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("List variable width cells");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(list);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And sample screenshot (with a selected element):

[image: Sample screenshot with one item selected.]